# What is 'calculator' package?

Tags: updates, calculator

[image: calculator appearing in software updater]

Whenever I am updating, calculator always needs updating.  I don't know what it is.  Can someone please let me know what this is?  It also shows up when I search in the dash, but it will not launch.

[image: Calculator in dash]

Answer (score 1):

That's a "normal" calculator with many many special functions and graphical as well.
It's function is getting improved all the time, so it needs to be updated often..

Check this page for more information :

[Ubuntu Calculator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gcalctool/)

Also check the versions which are available, so you can see the differences. it's huge :)

Comment: But when I search in the dash, it shows two calculators.  The normal one, and the one in the picture I posted above.